# How to make IIS website override the root web.config in an Asp.Net MVC website

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I have created two websites in IIS, both pointing to the same directory on my local machine. Each site needs to be identical except for the appSettings section of web config however both use the same web.config found in the solution.

Is it possible to get IIS to consume a different version of (or override) the web.config file so that each site can see different values for appSettings?

In the production environment there will be several identical websites that differ only in their configuration but all need to communicate with each other via http requests to various endpoints. I am trying to find a way of locally testing this communication without needing to duplicate everything (since the code should always be identical).

My current approach is to create two websites in IIS and attach to the process of the one I wish to debug (but they currently both have the same config so I can't observe any difference in behaviour between them). Although my question above stands, I would be grateful for advice on how to do this if I am approaching this in the wrong way.

Comment: Move the related settings to location tags in `applicationHost.config` or root `web.config`. It is highly recommended that you use two separate directories, though.